# Laravel 5.6 Authorizing actions using policies

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to implement a policy to block the edit functionality of a resource.

My route:

```
Route::resource('imagerequests', 'ImageRequestController');
```

My ImageRequestPolicy

```
class ImageRequestPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    const STATUS_EXECUTING = "executing";

    public function edit(ImageRequest $imageRequest)
    {
        return $imageRequest->status !== self::STATUS_EXECUTING;
    }
}
```

But I can still access the ´imagerequests/{id}/edit´ route

### EDIT

```
/**
 * The policy mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $policies = [
    ImageRequest::class => ImageRequestPolicy::class,
];

/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    //
}
```

ImageRequest Model

```
class ImageRequest extends Model
```

Edit ImageRequestController method

```
public function edit($id, ImageRequest $imageRequest)
{
    $this->authorize('edit', $imageRequest);

    $imageRequest = ImageRequest::findOrFail($id);
    $requestTypes = RequestType::all();
    $attachments = $this->imageRequestRepository->getAttachmentsListOfImageRequestById($id);

    return view('imagerequest.edit', compact('imageRequest', 'requestTypes', 'attachments'));
}
```

Comment: take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#authorizing-form-requests
you can authorize form request

Comment: @RomanBobrik I first need to prevent them from even accessing the form.

Comment: Show your controller@edit code.

Comment: @ArthurSamarcos Edited OP with controller@edit code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your edit method is wrong, it's first argument **must** be the user:

```
public function edit(User $user, ImageRequest $imageRequest)
{
    return $imageRequest->status !== self::STATUS_EXECUTING;
}
```

Add to your ImageRequestController, edit method:

```
public function edit(ImageRequest $imageRequest) {

$this->authorize('edit',$imageRequest);

...

}
```

The $user argument is automaticaly added by laravel.

Also you need to register the policy in AuthServiceProvider.

```
protected $policies = [
    ImageRequest::class => ImageRequestPolicy::class,
];
```

And ImageRequest must extend Model class. Is it a model or a illuminate\http\request ?

There's something wrong with your controller. You sair your route is:

/imagerequests/26/edit

In your controller you are injecting a new, blank ImageRequest, maybe that's why it's passing the authorize test. Try this:

```
public function edit($id, ImageRequest $imageRequest)
{
    $imageRequest = ImageRequest::findOrFail($id);

    $this->authorize('edit', $imageRequest);

    $requestTypes = RequestType::all();
    $attachments = $this->imageRequestRepository->getAttachmentsListOfImageRequestById($id);

    return view('imagerequest.edit', compact('imageRequest', 'requestTypes', 'attachments'));
}
```

Comment: I don't use the User argument, why do I need to put it there?

Comment: It's added automatically by laravel. If you don't use it, will get an error.

Comment: whats the status of that imagerequest?

Comment: I registered the policy in AuthServiceProvider (edited OP) and ImageRequest already extends Model

Comment: Status is 100% "executing"

Comment: Laravel will inject function arguments only by order if the requested arguments are not inferable by the type-hint. So in this case, it doesn't matter. But anyway, how do you display a form of a model without passing the model to the form? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: I edited OP with the full code of the edit method it will clear things up

Comment: Yay that works, but the $imageRequest gets overriden immediately do I need to type hint it?

Comment: You should use only one argument. Choose if you want to type hint function(ImageRequest $imageRequest) or get the ID and find it later in the method function($id)

Answer (score 0):

use middleware for protecting routes.

```
use App\Post;
Route::put('/post/{post}', function (Post $post) {
    // The current user may update the post...
})->middleware('can:update,post');
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I can't use this because I have a resource route look at my question

Comment: you can use it in your controller constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between gates and policies that is somewhat hard to grasp from the documentation. Gates are used to authorize controller methods while resources are responsible to authorize actions regarding models, i.e. actual database records.

So in your case, you should be using gates and not policies. You can still use your existing policy class, but you have to register it differently. Instead of using

```
/**
 * The policy mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $policies = [
    ImageRequest::class => ImageRequestPolicy::class,
];

/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
}
```

you should be using

```
/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::resource('imageRequests', App\Policies\ImageRequestPolicy::class);
}
```

For further reference, have a look at the [documentation on gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#gates).